# How to print text onTap of text in camera using OCR?

Tags: firebase, flutter, ocr

I am building OCR using flutter.
It detects the text live using camera and marks it down using CustomPainter.
[Click here to see example image](https://miro.medium.com/max/1466/1*WR1BNNLwfrfbEngoQyShiQ.png)

I am able to mark out text using rectanglur marker.
But now i want to print a particular text or line ontap of the box.
how can i achieve it?
i am using this example

[Example](https://miro.medium.com/max/1466/1*WR1BNNLwfrfbEngoQyShiQ.png)

```
 Widget _buildResults() {
const Text noResultsText = Text('No results!');

if (_scanResults == null ||
    _camera == null ||
    !_camera.value.isInitialized) {
  return noResultsText;
}

CustomPainter painter;

final Size imageSize = Size(
  _camera.value.previewSize.height,
  _camera.value.previewSize.width,
);

painter = TextDetectorPainter(imageSize, _scanResults);

return CustomPaint(
  painter: painter,
);
} 


 class TextDetectorPainter extends CustomPainter {
 TextDetectorPainter(this.absoluteImageSize, this.visionText);

  final Size absoluteImageSize;
  final VisionText visionText;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final double scaleX = size.width / absoluteImageSize.width;
 final double scaleY = size.height / absoluteImageSize.height;

Rect scaleRect(TextContainer container) {
  return Rect.fromLTRB(
    container.boundingBox.left * scaleX,
    container.boundingBox.top * scaleY,
    container.boundingBox.right * scaleX,
    container.boundingBox.bottom * scaleY,
  );
}

final Paint paint = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 1.0;

for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
  paint.color = Colors.black;
  canvas.drawRect(scaleRect(block), paint);
}
}

 @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TextDetectorPainter oldDelegate) {
  return oldDelegate.absoluteImageSize != absoluteImageSize ||
      oldDelegate.visionText != visionText;
}
 }
```

Comment: Can you share your code? Github or at least the mart where you create the boxes?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the same.

Comment: Probably [this](https://gist.github.com/sma/c6a9111d58c3deb83711106cec6152ee) can give you an idea

Comment: I have already seen this.This gave me some idea but i am still not able to crack it.Thanks though.